# get statistics on site activity by parsing catalina.out

Tags: java, logging

I want to write a script or a java app that will summarize statistic info on my site's activity.
I've thought of parsing catalina.out file (I use tomcat) for particular strings that would eventually give me what I need, but it seems that there should be another solution for this.

Any other ideas? 
Or any good library for helping with log file parsing?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you want to parse the log files yourself?

There are some free tools for monitoring Tomcat. Maybe you can look at http://code.google.com/p/javamelody/ for example?

Comment: Yes. I run a specific app on the webserver, and part of the things I need to parse is the log this app produces.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can turn on an access.log (configured in `server.xml`)

   `<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.FastCommonAccessLogValve" directory="logs" 
   prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt" pattern="%h %l %u %t %r %s %b %D %T" resolveHosts="false"/>`
2. You can manage the statistics that interest you in your web application. Simply manage some counters when your servlet is accessed.
3. You can monitor your Tomcat via JMX, using [JavaMelody](http://javamelody.googlecode.com), 
   Javamelody expose an API for monitoring "**traffic**, memory usage, threads, **requests**, CPU, **logs**, ...": (I marked in bold what you may possibly need)
   it is perfect in a production server.